# Eureka unavailable-replicas

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I created two instances of Eureka using Docker containers. It works like a charm:

- a service A registers with an Eureka instance 1
- a service B registers with an Eureka instance 2
- The Eureka instance 1 shows the services A and B => replication works
- The Eureka instance 2 shows the services A and B => replication works
- The service A discovers service B and makes a HTTP request successfully

But I cannot make neither instance of Eureka to show another one in `available-replicas`. The instance 1 shows the instance 2 in `registered-replicas` and `unavailable-replicas`.

Here is my code: https://github.com/vria/eureka-cluster-example

Thank you in advance folks.

P.S. I've read the docs and other suggestions on Stackoverflow. My instances have the same name and different hostnames. Replication seems to work. But still.

Answer (score 0):

I think easier to add alias to containers and pass that in properties.

Here is my code:
yml:

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: peer1
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer1
    statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}/info
    healthCheckUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}/health
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer2:8762/eureka/
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: peer2
server:
  port: 8762
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer2
    statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}/info
    healthCheckUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}/health
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer1:8761/eureka/
```

and the compose:

```
eureka-server1:
    container_name: eureka-server
    image: YOUR IMAGE
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=peer1
    networks:
      ant:
        aliases:
          - peer1
    volumes:
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    restart: always

  eureka-server2:
      container_name: eureka-server2
      image: YOUR IMAGE
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - 8762:8762
      environment:
        - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=peer2
      networks:
        ant:
          aliases:
            - peer2
      volumes:
        - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
        - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      restart: always
```

[image: eureka show available replicas]

Hope it helps